# Datatable server side pagination modification from javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

My count query is taking long time to execute. There is no option to optimize count query. Now I want to do something like the picture[image: row counter]

I tried with different way to modify the pagination. But could not get any success yet.

My workflow will be :

1. Search and take 10 results and show it
2. initiate count query in a separate http ajax request
3. when count query finish, initiate pagination of the table

Is there any option to do this in datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can suggest is,

- Show the table after count query was execute.
- Better to send count in response headers, So the count query will be reduced.

Comment: If I show the table after count then it's taking a long time to pull the data's which is boring to the users. And I am executing count query only one time.

Comment: When you try to get first 10 users, the count should be return in response headers. So they count query will be reduced. Try to show a animated loader

Comment: Most of the time, the count query will not take much time. kindly review the query again

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting me and I did the same thing. But my problem is When you try to get first 10 users, its taking a long time to get the result. For the second page it's pretty fast..

Comment: The pagination component will not well until you give total count. Hide the pagination component in DOM when query in processing, then show it.